# Reference for central product

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I am reading central product of groups from text Group Theory I by M Suzuki. But I am neither able to understand nor does getting a feel on what is happening. I will be thankful to you if you can tell me some easy reference regarding the central product. I will be happy to see some computations that is how to construct central product of two groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, and let $\phi$ be an isomorphism from a subgroup $Z$ of $Z(G)$ to a subgroup of $Z(H)$. Then we can define the central product of $G$ and $H$ with respect to $\phi$ as the quotient group

$G \circ_\phi H = (G \times H)/\{(z,\phi(z^{-1})) : z \in Z \}.$

The way to think of it is being the direct product, but with the elements $z$ and $\phi(z)$ identified for $z \in Z$.

With this general definition, the direct product itself is a special case with $Z=1$. But usually, the isomorphism is from $Z(G)$ to $Z(H)$, and the map $\phi$ is often left unspecified, particularly when all isomorphisms $Z(G) \to Z(H)$ define isomorphic central products.

As an example, let $G$ and $H$ be nonabelian groups of order 8, i.e. $Q_8$ or $D_8$. Then $|Z(G)|=|Z(H)|=2$, and their central product has order $8^2/2 = 32$ with centre of order 2. You can repeat this process, by taking central products of $n$ copies of $D_8$ or $Q_8$, giving groups $E$ of order $2^{2n+1}$ with centre of order 2 and $E/Z(E)$ elementary abelian. These are the so-called *extraspecial* groups, and there are two isomorphism types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now I again read the text and have the feeling but I do'nt understand one point of the proof of proposition 4.17, page 139 (third line from the top) which is following: how he concludes that $x \in H_1 \cap K_1Z$ and how he concludes that $H_1 \cap K_1Z=D_1$. I will be thankful to you if you could help me.

Comment: What is the point of having $z^{-1}$ in the definition of the quotient group? Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism oneself chooses, and inversion in commutative groups is an automorphism, isn't it kind of redundant?

Comment: I wrote $z^{-1}$ to fit the description of identifying $z$ with $\phi(z)$. You could define an alternative central product by using $z$ in place of $z^{-1}$ but in general that would not be isomorphic to the one defined with $z^{-1}$.