# One dubt is remained

Tags: group-theory

I apologizes if this question is considered as duplicate problem. In [Reference for central product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574338/reference-for-central-product), I asked the reference for central product and I am thankful to Derek Holt for explaining me the concept. I still have a doubt on a proposition from Group Theory I by M Suzuki. Following is Proposition 4.17 (with proof):

Proposition: Let $H_1$ and $K_1$ be two groups and $D_1$ be subgroup of $Z(H_1)$. Suppose in addition that an isomorphism from $D_1$ into $Z(K_1)$ is given. The subset $Z$ of the direct product $H_1 \times K_1$ consisting of elements of the form $(x,\varphi(x^{-1}))$, where $x \in D_1$, is a subgroup of $Z(H_1 \times K_1)$. The factor group $(H_1 \times K_1)/Z$ is a central product of $H=H_1Z/Z$ and $K=K_1Z/Z$. We have $H_1 \cong H$, $K_1 \cong K$ and the subgroup $D_1Z/Z$ of $H$ is identified with the subgroup $\varphi(D_1)Z/Z$ of $K$ via the isomorphism $\bar{\varphi}$ induced from $\varphi$.

Proof: It is easy to check that the set $Z$ is a subgroup of the center. Consider $H_1$ and $K_1$ as subgroups of the direct product. Then we have $H_1 \cap Z=\{1\}=K_1 \cap Z$ and the second isomorphism theorem proves that $H=H_1Z/Z=H_1$ and similarly $K_1 \cong K$. Set $G=(H_1 \times K_1)/Z$. Then $H$ and $K$ commute elementwise and $G=HK$. Thus $G$ is a central product of $H$ and $K$. Let $D=H \cap K$. **Then each element of $D$ is a coset containing an element of the form $(x,1)$ where $x \in H_1 \cap K_1Z=D_1$**. Conversely if $x \in D_1$, then $(x,1)=(x,\varphi(x^{-1}))(1, \varphi(x)) \in ZK_1$. Thus we must have have $D=D_1Z/Z=\varphi(D_1)Z/Z$, furthermore the elements $x$ and $\varphi(x)$ correspond to the same element of $G$.

Now my problem is (given in bold face above) how he concludes that $x \in H_1 \cap K_1Z$ and how he concludes that $H_1 \cap K_1Z=D_1$.

Comment: $H \cap K = (H_1Z \cap K_1Z)/Z$ so an element of $H \cap K$ has a representative  $h_1z \in H_1Z \cap K_1Z$. By multiplying this by $z^{-1}$ we get a representative in $H_1 \cap K_1Z$. The elements of $K_1Z$ all have the form $(x,\phi(x^{-1})(1,k_1)$, where the first component $x$ is in $D_1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Thanks. I appreciated for your kind help.